# How to uppercase first character after symbol - in php?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$foo = 'hello world';
$foo = ucwords($foo); // Hello World
```

But I have a sample other code:

```
$foo = 'hello-world';
$foo = ucwords($foo);
```

How to result is `Hello-World`

Comment: Split by `-`, uppercase each part of that array, then join by `-`.

Comment: (Unless dashes and spaces occur in the same string and should be kept.)

Answer (score 2):

Use `preg_replace_callback`

```
$foo = 'hello-world';
$foo = ucwordsEx($foo); 
echo $foo; // Hello-World
```

**Function Used**

```
function ucwordsEx($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback ( '/[a-z]+/i', function ($match) {
        return ucfirst ( $match [0] );
    }, $str );
}
```

[Live DEMO](https://eval.in/65600)

Comment: The OP asked for capitalization after the character `-`, not after a non-letter.  I'm not quite sure how I feel about the overhead of RegEx with such a basic case.

Comment: @L105 The title of the question says "symbol -", then goes ahead and uses the symbol `-` in an example.  Look at other people's perspectives and interpretation of bad English before commenting negatively.

Comment: Working on `How to result is Hello-World` .. the title might be misleading

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this problem quite a while back. This will preserve the hyphens, spaces, and other characters that may be in your string and capitalize on *any* word boundary.

```
// Convert a string to mixed-case on word boundaries.
function my_ucfirst($string) {
        $temp = preg_split('/(\W)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        foreach ($temp as $key => $word) {
                $temp[$key] = ucfirst($word);
        }
        return join ('', $temp);
}
```

Comment: Why not just `preg_replace()` and `ucfirst()` based on the first `\w` after a `\W` to reduce the overhead of splitting, then joining?

Comment: @BLaZuRE That should work. In the original, I am also converting all the rest of the letters to lowercase, though that wasn't asked for here in this question. I also wrote the code eight years ago...

Comment: If I were only doing a single transform, like `ucfirst()`, I'd probably do a `preg_replace_callback` (with a split on word boundaries, _not_ a split on strings of letters). The only real advantage here is that there are several points to throw in additional transformations (like the ones I stripped out for this example). There are many ways to do this, and the "right" one is going to be dictated by issues not given in the original question.

Comment: @BLaZuRE Hm. I think maybe that flag isn't needed anymore. I'll have to go back through all the ancient versions and try to figure out why it's there in the first place...